# python, igraph coping with vertex renumbering

Tags: python, igraph

I am implementing an algorithm for finding a dense subgraph in a directed graph using python+igraph. The main loop maintains two subgraphs S and T which are initially identical and removes nodes (and incident edges) accoriding to a count of the indegree (or outdegree) of those nodes with respect to the other graph.  The problem I have is that igraph renumbers the vertices so when I delete some from T, the remaining nodes no longer correspond to the same ones in S.

Here is the main part of the loop that is key.

```
def directed(S):
    T = S.copy()
    c = 2
    while(S.vcount() > 0 and T.vcount() > 0):
        if (S.vcount()/T.vcount() > c):
            AS = S.vs.select(lambda vertex: T.outdegree(vertex) < 1.01*E(S,T)/S.vcount())
            S.delete_vertices(AS)
        else:
            BT = T.vs.select(lambda vertex: S.indegree(vertex) < 1.01*E(S,T)/T.vcount())
            T.delete_vertices(BT)
```

This doesn't work because of the effect of deleting vertices on the vertex ids. Is there a standard workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to assign unique names to the vertices in the `name` vertex attribute. These are kept intact when vertices are removed (unlike vertex IDs), and you can use them to refer to vertices in functions like `indegree` or `outdegree`. E.g.:

```
>>> g = Graph.Ring(4)
>>> g.vs["name"] = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
>>> g.degree("C")
2
>>> g.delete_vertices(["B"])
>>> g.degree("C")
1
```

Note that I have removed vertex `B` so vertex `C` also gained a new ID, but the name is still the same.

In your case, the row with the `select` condition could probably be re-written like this:

```
AS = S.vs.select(lambda vertex: T.outdegree(vertex["name"]) < 1.01 * E(S,T)/S.vcount())
```

Of course this assumes that initially the vertex names are the same in `S` and `T`.

Comment: Thanks. How would that work if the graph is read in with Graph.Read_Ncol() (it has millions of nodes/edges)? Should I write a loop that names each vertex with its own id somehow?

Comment: You can assign names to all the vertices at once using `g.vs["name"] = list_of_names`, as I do above in my example (see the second line). But actually, if you use `Graph.Read_Ncol`, the name attribute is already there, it contains the names from the original NCOL file.